# Creating text fields according to user's input in JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create text fields according to user's input and show the text fields through JavaScript function but this code is not working!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Create text Fields according to the users choice!</title>

    <script type="script/JavaScript">
        function createTextField(){

            var userInput = parseInt(document.form2.txtInput.view);

            for(var i=0; i<=userInput;i++)
            {
                document.write('<input type="text">');
            }


        }

    </script>
</head>
 <form action="http://localhost.WebProg.php" method="post" name="form2">
    <p>How many text fields you want to create? Enter the number below!</p>
    Input: <input type="text" name="txtInput">
    <input type="button" name="btnInput" value="Create" onclick="createTextField();">
 </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Replace this line:

```
 var userInput = parseInt(document.form2.txtInput.view);
```

To

```
var userInput = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('txtInput')[0].value);
```

```js
  function createTextField(){
 // alert(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
            var userInput = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('txtInput')[0].value);

            for(var i=0; i<userInput;i++)
            {
                document.write('<input type="text">');
            }


        }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Create text Fields according to the users choice!</title>
</head>
 <form action="http://localhost.WebProg.php" method="post" name="form2">
    <p>How many text fields you want to create? Enter the number below!</p>
    Input: <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput">
    <input type="button" name="btnInput" value="Create" onclick="createTextField();">
 </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `document.write`. The correct way to do it is to append the `input`s to a `div`.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4x01np4/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost.WebProg.php" method="post" name="form2">
    <p>How many text fields you want to create? Enter the number below!</p>Input:
    <input type="text" name="txtInput" />
    <input type="button" name="btnInput" value="Create" />
    <div></div>
</form>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];

btn.onclick = function () {
    var userInput = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value, 10);
    for (var i = 0; i <= userInput - 1; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML += "<input type='text' />"
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is better option to add dynamic input/div's easy to manipulate DOM. 
Check the  following code

```
<div class="box">
    <label> Enter input value </label>
    <input type="number" id="in_num"/>
    <button type="button" id="submit"> submit </button>
    <h3> Append input values</h3>
    <div id="dynamicInput"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#submit').click(function(){     
     var inputIndex = $('#in_num').val();
        for( var i=0; i<inputIndex; i++)
        {
          $('#dynamicInput').append('<input type=text  id=id_'+ i +'/>');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo URl: http://jsfiddle.net/sathyanaga/75vbgesm/3/

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
var userInput = parseInt(document.form2.txtInput.view);
```

To:

```
var userInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtInput").value);
```

And give the input textbox an id (I used "txtInput", but it can be anything). 
I believe you also need to change the loop from, when I typed "2" it created 3 inputs instead of 2.

Comment: where is the Id he mentioned?